# Some weird behavior of Chrome (FF too) when debugging javascript part of JSF composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I'm making JSF composite component, something simple with the following code:

```
<cc:implementation componentType="timePickerComponent">

    <div id="#{cc.clientId}" style="#{cc.attrs.style}">
        
        <h:outputScript name="js/timepicker/timepicker_helper.js"/>
        
            <p:autoComplete id="timepicker"
                    scrollHeight="200"
                    onfocus="openAutocompletePanel(this);"
                    widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.widgetVar}"
                    completeMethod="#{cc.completeMethod}" 
                    value="#{cc.timeLocal}"  
                    size="5"/>
        
        
    </div>

</cc:implementation>
```

And `timepicker_helper.js` which contains only single function:

```
function openAutocompletePanel(field){
    console.log("ups");
    console.log(field);
}
```

When I try to debug `openAutocompletePanel` function in Chrome developer tools, i.e. defining breakpoints at the beginning or at the middle of the function it doesn't work. But function itself is invoked, it prints to console.

When I added row `debugger;` in the middle of the `openAutocompletePanel`, it has stopped at this point but instead of file `timepicker_helper.js` Chrome has opened file `VM3339`.

There is snapshot of my screen:
[image]

This isn't first time I debug JSF's javascript in Chrome but first time I've met this issue. What could cause such behavior?

Thank you.

UPDATE:

Ok, it was my fault.
**BalusC** said many time that when you include *javascript* in *composite component* you should specify `target="head"` otherwise it will be loaded multiple time.
When I changed loading sentence to `<h:outputScript  name="js/timepicker/timepicker_helper.js" target="head"/>` the problem has gone.
I cannot consider this as answer because I not sure 100% if I right.

Comment: Does it work with another plain jsf component instead of p:autocomplete?

Comment: @Kukeltje, no. I tried add `<h:inputText onfocus="..."/>` and it open tab with the different name `VM4037` but not reached the actual file.

Comment: I suspect that it's intended behavior but don't sure. Just checked my old code and it's first time I use `javascript` in such scenario, together with JSF elements in composite component and loading the page by `<h:outputScript>`.

Comment: @Kukeltje, you're right, it's irrelevant to current topic, so I've removed mention of the scoping from original topic.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, cant put it into comment, so put it as an answer...

The such behavior could be if timepicker_helper.js is loaded and executed by JavaScript `eval();` function.

In this case developer console will show the common file where your origin file has been included, like you see: VM3339.
And `debugger;`  is the only way to break inside in this case.

Comment: Thank you. It's make things more clear, but I still don't understand is it intended behavior in JSF scenario.

Comment: If you include js file in your view via <script/> tag it should load it as is. But I think it could use eval() if you are using <h:outputScript/> in example.